# $this->query callback in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I need *open a transaction*, and wait the **return** for do commit or rollback.

But, how can I get return (true/false - not exception or any "break process") of this query?

```
$this->query('update checks set discount = 100 where check_num = 3001');
```

In my tests, when an error occurs, it stops the whole process and returns an exception.

I do not want it, just want to know: **has successfully executed or error**? (true / false)

Comment: why is that tagged cakephp if you are not using it? updateAll() would be the right way to go here...

Comment: Because I'm using CakePHP O_O, and the query is "big query" (not that above). As I know, is recommended execute big query using this method `query()`. But, I'm not a expert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What mark said in the comments seems accurate, an [updateAll()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-array-conditions) call would seem more appropriate to achieve what you want. If you ever find yourself in a situation where you actually do need transactions, there are examples on how to achieve that in [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/transactions.html) as well.